# What is the Path for LTS? 4.7?

Tags: upgrade, lts

We have our production site on 4.6, the current LTS.  I'd like to know what the thoughts are on the next version of LTS.  Will it eventually be 4.7?  Approximately when might that switch happen?

If there is a page already sharing this information, apologies, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The LTS as you know it is the last one!

Eileen explained the details here: https://civicrm.org/blog/eileen/the-lts-going-forwards

Essentially the idea is that through better release/QA/testing we can make the current 4.7 the Long Term Stable release. In combination with the fact that innovative ideas / new features are going to be housed in extensions.

Comment: I agree with Karin's answer but would add that some folks in the community intend to ensure 4.6 continues to get security releases if not bug fix backports or API backports alongvthe lines of what Eileen (and Nicolas) did for years.